# border left in printing css of body tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing-web-page

I am trying to print a body with border left for the body tag...
but the problem is its not touching both the top and bottom sides of the paper...
i removed the padding but strill not working...
providing my code below....

http://jsfiddle.net/jjnKP/embedded/result/

```
@media print {
        body {margin:0; padding:0; line-height: 1.4em; word-spacing:1px; letter-spacing:0.2px; font: 17px Arial, Helvetica,"Lucida Grande", serif; color: #000;}
        .mainDiv, .navbar, .copyright  {
            display: none;
        }

        #templateTwoPadding {
                padding: 0 0;
            }

            #tableHeadingLastDF{text-align: left;width: 134px; border:1px solid white;}
            #makeLeftDF{text-align: left;}

            .jumbotron .lead {
                font-size: 12px;
                width: 670px;
            }

            #listWidthDF{
                width: 670px;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Does the printer support and have you set it to borderless printing and chosen the correct paper size? You can't set borderless printing in CSS alone.

Comment: That white margin is decided by a combination of the Printer, It's driver, and the User's settings.

Comment: did you set the margin of the HTML tag to 0?

Comment: @Raffael: thanks for your reply....I have given body tag margin as O and not html tag is that fine....